# How to process big data continuously in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

hey，guys！I am trying to process big data continuously in OpenCV. Here is my code:

```
vector<Point2f> up_imagePoints;
vector<Point2f> left_imagePoints;
vector<Point2f> right_imagePoints;

Mat frame1_silhouette;
Mat frame2_silhouette;
Mat frame3_silhouette;

Mat frame1_reconstruction;
Mat frame2_reconstruction;
Mat frame3_reconstruction;

for ( int i = 0; i < 16777216; ++i ){
        //check point range
        if (up_imagePoints[i].x >= col_bound || up_imagePoints[i].y >= row_bound) {
            coor_test = 1;}
        else if (left_imagePoints[i].x >= col_bound || left_imagePoints[i].y >= row_bound) {
            coor_test = 1;}
        else if (right_imagePoints[i].x >= col_bound || right_imagePoints[i].y >= row_bound) {
            coor_test = 1;}
        //check silhouette
        if (coor_test == 0) {
            if (frame1_silhouette.at<uchar>((cvFloor(up_imagePoints[i].x)),(cvFloor(up_imagePoints[i].y))) == 255)
                value_test = 1;
            else if (frame2_silhouette.at<uchar>((cvFloor(left_imagePoints[i].x)),(cvFloor(left_imagePoints[i].y))) == 255)
                value_test = 1;
            else if (frame3_silhouette.at<uchar>((cvFloor(right_imagePoints[i].x)),(cvFloor(right_imagePoints[i].y))) == 255)
                value_test = 1;

            if (value_test == 0) {
                frame1_reconstruction.at<uchar>((cvFloor(up_imagePoints[i].x)),(cvFloor(up_imagePoints[i].y))) = 255;
                frame2_reconstruction.at<uchar>((cvFloor(left_imagePoints[i].x)),(cvFloor(left_imagePoints[i].y))) = 255;
                frame3_reconstruction.at<uchar>((cvFloor(right_imagePoints[i].x)),(cvFloor(right_imagePoints[i].y))) = 255;}
            }

        value_test = 0;
        coor_test = 0;
        cout<<"round "<<i<<endl;
        }
```

The sizes of up_iamgePoints, left_imagePoints and right_imagePoints are 1x16777216. They contain the coordinates of images. The sizes of framex_silhouette and framex_reconstruction are 480x640

There are three steps:

1. check whether coordinates of x_imagePoints are within the range: col_bound(640) and row_bound(480)
2. check whether the same positions of framex_silhouette are all 255
3. apply 255 to the positions from step 2 to framex_reconstruction

The program always fail in a different state, like when i == 1900566

Does any body know how to process big data continuously in OpenCV without errors ?

Comment: what is the 'z' index used for ? why do you never initialize 'i' ?

Comment: @berak, I have reedited the code for clear explanation. 'x','y','z'indexes are used to explain a big voxel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have images 480 (rows) x 640 (cols), but you are trying to get Mat value from `Mat.at<uchar>(colNumber, rowNumber)`. At some point `Mat::at()` will throw an error because you will try to get a value that is outside `Mat` bounds.

Comment: I checked the range of coordinates before that. If the coordinates are outside the Mat bounds, the coor_test  will become 1.

Comment: But you are checking them incorrectly: coordinates wich you are using as ROWS you are validating for COLUMNS bounds and these you are using as COLUMNS you are validating for ROWS bounds. To get a value from a Mat you have to use ROWS,COLS coordinate system. Thats way you are getting errors in different places because many of this reversed coordinates will be correct in the maner of Mat bounds.